# How to know which key point match which in an image

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using an ORB to Featured Matching two images. One is a frame from a TV show, the other one is the logo. If the logo is within the frame, it means the TV program is on. If it's not within the frame, it means the TV is running a commercial block.

In order to do this, I've set a rectangle in the frame which contains the TV logo. Then, I'm checking which key points are contained in the rectangle section. This is the fraction of code which does that.

```
def pointatRectangulo(x,y,width,height,ptx,pty):
    resultado = x < ptx < x+width and y < pty < y+height
    return resultado

    rectX = 1100
    rectY = 600
    rectWidth = 1180 - rectX
    rectHeight = 670 - rectY
    cv2.rectangle(frame,(rectX,rectY),(1180,670),(0,255,0),3)

    bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
    matches = bf.match(des1, des2)

    cent = False
    cont = 0

    for m in matches:
        frame_idx = m.queryIdx
        logo_idx = m.trainIdx
        (x1,y1) = pc1[frame_idx].pt
        (x2,y2) = pc2[logo_idx].pt
        lista_pc1.append((x1, y1))
        lista_pc2.append((x2, y2))

    for point in lista_pc1:
        cent = pointatRectangulo(rectX,rectY,rectWidth,rectHeight,point[0],point[1])
        if (cent == True):
            cont = cont + 1
#if cont > 5, then the TV is running a TV show and not a commercial block.
```

Of course, after thinking I had the problem solved, I noticed that I was just asking the algorithm if a key point from the original frame was in the rectangle section of that same frame, instead of asking if a key point from the logo matched with a key point from the frame within the aforementioned rectangle.

I've consulted some OpenCV documentation and I don't get any solutions to perform this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, `bf.match` gives you the matches between key points. And you also used in in your code already. See [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/dc/dc3/tutorial_py_matcher.html) for an example.

Comment: @QuangHoang Yes, but it doesn't give you the coordinates between points matched, right? I mean, X,Y point matches with X2,Y2 point. Which I need, in order to check if the point matched is within the rectangle section I'm talking about.

Comment: here I thought `(x1,y1) = pc1[frame_idx].pt` are the coordinates, no?

Comment: @QuangHoang Yes. If the coordinates in x1,y1 match the coordinates in x2,y2 AND this x2,y2 coordinates are within the rectangle section, cont++. But I don't know how to relate both points in the IF statement.